# How can I draw a triangle in an image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, triangular

I need to draw a triangle in an image I have loaded. The triangle should look like this:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0  
1 1 0 0 0 0  
1 1 1 0 0 0  
1 1 1 1 0 0  
1 1 1 1 1 0  
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

But the main problem I have is that I do not know how I can create a matrix like that. I want to multiply this matrix with an image, and the image matrix consists of 3 parameters (W, H, RGB).

Answer (score 9):

You can create a matrix like the one in your question by using the [TRIL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/tril.html) and [ONES](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ones.html) functions:

```
>> A = tril(ones(6))

A =

     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comment below, it sounds like you have a 3-D RGB image matrix `B` and that you want to multiply each color plane of `B` by the matrix `A`. This will have the net result of setting the upper triangular part of the image (corresponding to all the zeroes in `A`) to black. Assuming `B` is a 6-by-6-by-3 matrix (i.e. the rows and columns of `B` match those of `A`), here is one solution that uses indexing (and the function [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html)) instead of multiplication:

```
>> B = randi([0 255],[6 6 3],'uint8');  % A random uint8 matrix as an example
>> B(repmat(~A,[1 1 3])) = 0;           % Set upper triangular part to 0
>> B(:,:,1)                             % Take a peek at the first plane

ans =

    8    0    0    0    0    0
  143  251    0    0    0    0
  225   40  123    0    0    0
  171  219   30   74    0    0
   48  165  150  157  149    0
   94   96   57   67   27    5
```

The call to REPMAT replicates a negated version of `A` 3 times so that it has the same dimensions as `B`. The result is used as a [logical index](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/sept01/matrix.html) into `B`, setting the non-zero indices to 0. By using indexing instead of multiplication, you can avoid having to worry about converting `A` and `B` to the same data type (which would be required to do the multiplication in this case since `A` is of type `double` and `B` is of type `uint8`).

Comment: Lower triangular matrix function outclasses homerolled solutions.

Comment: Thank you this was good. my problem here is I want to multiply this matrix with matrix contain image ::> and the matrix contain image consist of 3 parameter (W,H,RGB) 
plz try it and see problem , then help me ..

thank you